# How to stop Windows from auto locking the screen?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have a laptop, running Windows 7,  which stays at home all the time. It's connected to a company. Lately, it started to auto lock after 10 minutes of inactivity. I figured it's a group policy that got set up from the company. However as shown below, all the entries were set to 'Not Configured' and I set the ones that I thought might help to 'Disabled' and rebooted.

- I also set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut from 600 to 11600 to make it a much longer time.
- Control Panel -> Personalization -> Screen Saver was and is set to None

These changes didn't have any effect. It seems I am missing a setting. Any ideas what settings I still need to modify?

[image]

Comment: Disable energy saving in system settings.

Comment: @bjoster That doesn't help. How does a computer save energy when it locks the screen? It's still the same amount of energy being used.

Comment: It does - the default behaviour of Windows 10 is 'saving energy' which locks the screen and blacks it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use any one of the tools which move the mouse at a certain period of times. The screen won't lock then.

Answer (score 4):

The registry keys are likey being set via group policy preferences. It wouldn't be visible in that view.

Either way it probably isn't a good idea to try and bypass security policy.